# Plugin used only on some pages - not widget

Tags: plugins, facebook

Im using 'Cool FB like' plugin which displays a css fixed facebook logo on the right. When we hover that logo, fan page box is showing up.

The problem is that I need to change fanpage on some pages. Do you have any idea how to manage that?

I have an idea - I can use one plugin on some pages and another - similar one, on others but this plugin isn't a widget so i can't set where to display plugin up.

Maybe You have some other ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Try to post the specifics about the plugin: Plugin Link, How does it work, Code used, How you implement it, What did you try. Otherwise, you're left at the (slim) chance of another user of the plugin finding this Question. Please, [edit] the Question to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved id by myself.

For those who want do the same trick:
go to bliss-facebook-likebox plugin folder, edit cool-fb-likebox.php.
Near the bottom of file there will be an $url variable.

Change:

```
$url = urlencode($get_cfbl_options['fbpageurl']);
```

to:

```
wp_reset_query();
global $post;
$site-id = 1; // use your own needed number

if( is_page($site-id) || $post->post_parent == '.$site-id.') {
    $url = urlencode('https://www.facebook.com/pages/Your-Fanpage');
} else {
    $url = urlencode($get_cfbl_options['fbpageurl']); //editable in plugin options
}
```